# FontAwesome 4.3.0 icons not displaying properly on my site

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm having trouble getting FontAwesome 4.3.0 to display correctly on my page.  In the head section I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The fonts within the first style sheet work fine, but the fonts within **4.3.0 do not.**

[Here is my demo site.](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/mvp/demo.html)

- Demos 1, 3, and 6 have surrounding circles that appear stretched horizontally. These
  fonts are all from 4.3.0
- Demos 2, 4 and 5 are fine.

See problem here:

[image]

Also, when you make the viewport only like 320px wide, the 4.3.0 fonts get pushed into the side of the green circle they're within like this:

[image: wrong]

Here is a direct link to the working css file:  [LINK](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/mvp/css/main.css)

**The html code for one of the non-working fonts is:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="500ms"  data-wow-delay="900ms">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <div class="service-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-diamond fa-2x"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="service-desc">
                                <h3>Demo3</h3>
                                <p>Demo</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**and here's the CSS for service-icon:**

```
.service-icon {
border: 1px solid #2ECC71;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #2ECC71;
float: left;
padding: 10px 13px;
}
```

I couldn't get a codepen demo working but will try again if you insist.

How do I make all icons appear properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set a specific width and height to `.service-icon`, so it's size is more or less decided by the size of the font-awesome glyph. So that means you will only get perfect circles for glyphs that are perfectly square. Force `.service-icon` to be a square, and you will get proper circles.

The centering issue is caused by the same thing; you apply the same padding to everything, whether or not its a square, so only square glyphs get centered. use `text-align : center` to center horizontally, and the `line-height = div height` trick to center vertically. I used a size of `4em x 4em` but you might want to play with that:

```
.service-icon {
    border: 1px solid #2ECC71;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #2ECC71;
    float: left;
    line-height:4em;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```